# InvalidQueryParameterValue when trying to upload to Azure blob storage from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps that uses `az storage blob upload-batch` to upload some files from an Angular build to Azure blob storage (with `Static Website` feature enabled).

```
az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "dist/myAngularApp" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key "somekey"
    --account-name "osimanagementdev"
```

When I run this command locally, it uploads just fine to my `$web` location, but when running within the pipeline it fails with `InvalidQueryParameterValue`

I also tried the parameter `--auth-mode "key"` but didn't help much.
The agent runs on a `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS` image.

How can I get `az` to upload files from a build to Azure blob storage?

Comment: More than likely the issue is with the version of the CLI tools. `$web` blob container is a rather new thing and by blob container's naming convention it is an invalid name. It is quite possible that the version of CLI tools do not understand how to deal with `$web` as blob container name.

Comment: good point @GauravMantri, the build logs do state that 40 updates are available. Any idea how I can check which extension might be the issue? I can see `storage` for instance: I am on 2.4.2 and the image is on 2.3.2...

Comment: Unfortunately I've not worked with Azure DevOps so I will not be able to comment with 100% guarantee but my guess would be `storage`.

Comment: this might help you: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10131 "$web is not a valid container name" "if $web isn't a variable, ...$ cannot be used as an destination name"